# mono is not recognized as an internal or external command vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am trying to build my VS2012 solution, with Nuget package restore enabled and I receive the following error

```
'mono' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Also this error

```
(path to soln nuget folder)\.nuget\NuGet.targets(97,9): error MSB3073: The command "mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 "(path to soln nuget folder)\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "(path to project folder)\packages.config" -source ""   -RequireConsent -solutionDir "(path to root of project)"" exited with code 9009.
```

Any idea why this is failing?

Comment: Are you building the project on Windows or Mac?

Comment: building on windows 7

Comment: OK that means there is something being incorrectly run from the NuGet.targets file. It looks like it is not detecting Windows and trying to run NuGet.exe install with mono. There is a line in the NuGet.targets file `<NuGetCommand Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 $(NuGetExePath)</NuGetCommand>`. This should not be run on Windows. You might be able to see what is going on by running `msbuild YourSolution.sln /v:diag > build.log` from the command line. The build.log file may show what is going on with that condition.

Comment: So your options are: 1) look into why NuGet.targets is failing and try to fix it. 2) Modify NuGet.targets so the mono command is not used. 3) Stop using the MSBuild based package restore and remove the NuGet.targets file referenced in your project file.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, one of your own `.targets` files redefined `OS`.

Look for `<OS Condition="...">...</OS>`. If you find such condition definition then it's going to confuse NuGet which expects `$(OS)` to return the value for the `OS` environment variable which is `Windows_NT` by default on Windows.